# 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email address when sending email in Outlook.com custom domain

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

I am trying to send a mail from my website through `smtp.live.com` port `587`. I verified the credentials and even tried to send the email from Gmail by adding the account there and sending through it. On Gmail it works, on my server it doesn't

I get the following error :

```
{ [SenderError: Mail from command failed - 501 5.5.4 Invalid Email address] name: 'SenderError', data: '501 5.5.4 Invalid Email address' }
```

I am using [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) to send the mail

Can anyone give me some information about this error message ?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the module that sent the email didn't specify a `from` field and it was sending it blank. The Outlook smtp server wasn't tolerant about this and threw an error.

Specifically adding `from` to the email solved the problem